# Changing promethus `job` label from `kubelet` to `kubernetes-cadvisor`

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, cadvisor

I'm working with a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster, and I want my `VerticalPodAutoscalers` to [use Prometheus as a history provider](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-use-prometheus-as-a-history-provider-for-the-vpa-recommender).
The instructions say:

> Configure your Prometheus to get metrics from cadvisor. Make sure that the metrics from the cadvisor have the label job=kubernetes-cadvisor.

I am installing Prometheus on my cluster via Helm, using the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack) chart.
It appears that the default `job` label for `cadvisor` metrics in this chart is `job='kubelet`;
I'm looking at the [source code for the chart](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack), but I don't understand how to manipulate the chart values to change the job label to `kubernetes-cadvisor`. What is the correct way to do this?

Under my Prometheus configuration, the only mention of `cadvisor` I can find is:

```
- job_name: monitoring/prometheus-operator-kubelet/1
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor
  scheme: https
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names:
      - kube-system
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_k8s_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: kubelet
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: https-metrics
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_k8s_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: https-metrics
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__metrics_path__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: metrics_path
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the following values to Helm:

```
kubelet:
  serviceMonitor:
    cAdvisor: false

# Add a scrape job for cAdvisor in accordance with the Prometheus docs
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
        scheme: https
        metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
```

Comment: This helped me - thanks! - but I seem to have a new problem now: Some of the graphs in the bundled Grafana dashboards are now broken. Was this something you also experienced after making this change?

Comment: No sorry. Have you got any custom config running in grafana, or is it the default shipped with kube-prometheus-stack that breaks?

Comment: This is only the default ones that ship with kube-prometheus-stack. Most graphs still work, but it seems like the ones that relate to CPU metrics stop receiving data

Comment: I asked a new question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406120/changing-prometheus-job-label-in-scraper-for-cadvisor-breaks-grafana-dashboards