# Changing Prometheus job label in scraper for cAdvisor breaks Grafana dashboards

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I installed Prometheus on my Kubernetes cluster with Helm, using the community chart [kube-prometheus-stack](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack) - and I get some beautiful dashboards in the bundled Grafana instance. I now wanted the recommender from the Vertical Pod Autoscaler to use Prometheus as a data source for historic metrics, [as described here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-use-prometheus-as-a-history-provider-for-the-vpa-recommender). Meaning, I had to make a change to the Prometheus scraper settings for cAdvisor, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65421764/310937) pointed me in the right direction, as after making that change I can now see the correct `job` tag on metrics from cAdvisor.

Unfortunately, now some of the charts in the Grafana dashboards are broken. It looks like it no longer picks up the CPU metrics - and instead just displays "No data" for the CPU-related charts.

So, I assume I have to tweak the charts to be able to pick up the metrics correctly again, but I don't see any obvious places to do this in Grafana?

Not sure if it is relevant for the question, but I am running my Kubernetes cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

This is the full `values.yaml` I supply to the Helm chart when installing Prometheus:

```yaml
kubeControllerManager:
  enabled: false
kubeScheduler:
  enabled: false
kubeEtcd:
  enabled: false
kubeProxy:
  enabled: false
kubelet:
  serviceMonitor:
    # Diables the normal cAdvisor scraping, as we add it with the job name "kubernetes-cadvisor" under additionalScrapeConfigs
    # The reason for doing this is to enable the VPA to use the metrics for the recommender
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-use-prometheus-as-a-history-provider-for-the-vpa-recommender
    cAdvisor: false
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    retention: 15d
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          # the azurefile storage class is created automatically on AKS
          storageClassName: azurefile
          accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 50Gi
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
        scheme: https
        metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor
        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
          insecure_skip_verify: true
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node
        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
```

Kubernetes version: 1.21.2

kube-prometheus-stack version: 18.1.1

helm version: version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.6.3", GitCommit:"d506314abfb5d21419df8c7e7e68012379db2354", GitTreeState:"dirty", GoVersion:"go1.16.5"}

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use?

Comment: @kkopczak This is on version 1.21.2 - I will update the question with that information as well

Comment: Which version of Helm did you use? Also, please, provide your logs.

Comment: @kkopczak I added the helm version to the question as well now. When you say provide logs, are you referring to logs from helm? - maybe using the `--debug` flag when installing Prometheus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have access to Azure AKS, so I've reproduced this issue on my GKE cluster. Below I'll provide some explanations that may help to resolve your problem.

First you can try to execute this `node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate` rule to see if it returns any result:

[image]

If it doesn't return any records, please read the following paragraphs.

### Creating a scrape configuration for cAdvisor

Rather than creating a completely new scrape configuration for cadvisor, I would suggest using one that is generated by default when `kubelet.serviceMonitor.cAdvisor: true`, but with a few modifications such as changing the label to `job=kubernetes-cadvisor`.

In my example, the 'kubernetes-cadvisor' scrape configuration looks like this:

**NOTE:** I added this config under the `additionalScrapeConfigs` in the `values.yaml` file (the rest of the `values.yaml` file may be like yours).

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor
  scheme: https
  authorization:
    type: Bearer
    credentials_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app_kubernetes_io_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: kubelet
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_k8s_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: kubelet
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: https-metrics
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: https-metrics
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__metrics_path__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: metrics_path
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    namespaces:
      names:
      - kube-system
```

#### Modifying Prometheus Rules

By default, Prometheus rules fetching data from cAdvisor use `job="kubelet"` in their PromQL expressions:

[image]

After changing `job=kubelet` to `job=kubernetes-cadvisor`, we also need to modify this label in the Prometheus rules:
**NOTE:** We just need to modify the rules that have `metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor` (these are rules that retrieve data from cAdvisor).

```
$ kubectl get prometheusrules prom-1-kube-prometheus-sta-k8s.rules -o yaml
...
  - name: k8s.rules
    rules:
    - expr: |-
        sum by (cluster, namespace, pod, container) (
          irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{job="kubernetes-cadvisor", metrics_path="/metrics/cadvisor", image!=""}[5m])
        ) * on (cluster, namespace, pod) group_left(node) topk by (cluster, namespace, pod) (
          1, max by(cluster, namespace, pod, node) (kube_pod_info{node!=""})
        )
      record: node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate
...
here we have a few more rules to modify...
```

After modifying Prometheus rules and waiting some time, we can see if it works as expected. We can try to execute `node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate` as in the beginning.

Additionally, let's check out our Grafana to make sure it has started displaying our dashboards correctly:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this awesome answer @kkopczak - I will try to take some time to test this ASAP

Comment: @kkopczak I have now tried out your suggestion, and it works perfectly! - thanks a lot for taking the time to write up this answer. To get the rules I had to run `kubectl get prometheusrules --namespace prometheus prometheus-kube-prometheus-k8s.rules -o yaml > rules.yaml` then I modified the file as you instructed, and then I ran `kubectl apply -f rules.yaml --record --namespace prometheus` to apply the changes (we have prometheus in a separate namespace)

Comment: This example was the only one which I could find that worked for me as well. I was able to see the scrape job in `Status > Configuration` and copied it. Then I commented out the servicemonitor and pasted the scrape job into the additional scrape configs.