# Correct configuration of Prometheus ServiceMonitor to scrape RabbitMQ Metrics

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, prometheus

I'm trying to make Prometheus find metrics from RabbitMQ (and a few other services, but the logic is the same).
My current configuration is:

```yaml
# RabbitMQ Service
# This live in the `default` namespace
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1

metadata:
  name: rabbit-metrics-service
  labels:
    name: rabbit-metrics-service

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 15692
      targetPort: 15692  
  selector:
    # This selects the deployment and it works
    app: rabbitmq
```

I then created a `ServiceMonitor`:

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor

metadata:
  # The name of the service monitor
  name: rabbit-monitor
  # The namespace it will be in
  namespace: kube-prometheus-stack
  labels:
    # How to find this service monitor
    # The name I should use in `serviceMonitorSelector`
    name: rabbit-monitor

spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 5s
    port: metrics
    path: /metrics

  # The namespace of origin service
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - default

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      # Where the monitor will attach to
      name: rabbit-metrics-service
```

`kube-prometheus-stack` has the following `values.yml`

```yaml
# values.yml
prometheusSpec:
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name:
      - rabbit-monitor
```

So from what I understand is: in the `metadata/label` section I define a `labelKey/labelValue` pair, and then reference this pair on the `selector/matchLabels`. I then add a custom `serviceMonitorSelector` that will match N labels. If it finds the labels, Prometheus should discover the `ServiceMonitor`, and hence, the `metrics` endpoint, and start scraping. But I guess there's something wrong with this logic. I tried a few other variations of this as well, but no success.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Documentation usually uses the same `name` everywhere, so I can quite understand where exactly should that name come from, since I tend to prefer to add `-service`, `-deployment` suffixes to the resources to be able to easily identify them later. I already add RabbitMQ prometheus plugin, and the endpoint seems to be working fine.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster? Maybe [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406120/changing-prometheus-job-label-in-scraper-for-cadvisor-breaks-grafana-dashboards/69855888#69855888) will help you?

Comment: @kkopczak I'm on 1.20.15 hosted on DigitalOcean. The cluster is managed, and I installed `kube-prometheus-stack` with helm, and `rabbit` manually (wrote my own manifests, will probably change to the helm version soon). Do you reckon this can be provider specific? I was thinking that my configurations are messed up

Comment: Thanks for the link, I looked at your answer. At the moment Prometheus and Grafana work fine for the cluster metrics, I can access prometheus dashboards and see the targets and metrics, all works well, I just can't seem to add extra targets

Comment: I have installed prometheus and rabitmq is running in my loacal windows machine(http://localhost:15672/)

Is it possible to integrate rabbimq and prometheus in my local?